# How to get multi tab view effect in Swiper.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swiper.js

i am using swiper.js JavaScript libraries

This Image http://i62.tinypic.com/2q084gg.jpg

Image link http://share.pho.to/9ohWC

Pretty much sums up everything I want to have in my HTML file.

i  just want to add tab naming "TAB Name"  and "X" close button 
on top of tab .

*Tabs It’s like Cover Flow, but vertical!

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Swiper demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/swiper.min.css">

    <!-- Demo styles -->
    <style>
    html, body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
    }
    body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {

     width: 100%;
     height: 90%;
     max-width: 400px;
     max-height:600px;
     -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -webkit-perspective: 1000s; 
     -webkit-perspective-origin: 100% 30%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;
        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 "> Swipe Vertically in coverflow </h1>
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/1)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/2)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/3)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/4)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/5)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/6)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/7)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/8)"></div>

            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/10)"></div>


        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="../dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->




    <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        effect: 'coverflow' ,

        grabCursor: true,
        centeredSlides: true,
         direction: 'vertical',
          mousewheelControl: true,
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        coverflow: {

             rotate: 10,
             stretch: 0,
            depth: 100,
            modifier: 6,
            slideShadows : true
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: u have some problem with me T__T tell me if u already solve this problem